# Finishing this JSON reading Android

Tags: android, json

Hello guys i'm starting android development and currently i'm testing some basic search the UI is like this:

1 EditText: where the user writes something that wants to search example Android
2 Button: when click this button i want to do all the process of searching for that particular topic using the google search api

https:/ /ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Android

i think i have right the json parser but i'm getting and NetworkOnMainException something like that..

MainActivity.java :

> http://pastebin.com/4CCmviBR#

JSONParser.java:

> http://pastebin.com/Ue630Eqs

the JSON:

`http://pastebin.com/kw1qDuvS`

please guys help me out

Comment: in case you miss this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: thanks for answer, EntryLevelDev i check the link you prived but i'm not clear yet in the doInBackground() needs parameters and also a return type.. what type you think is the one i need??

Comment: Nathan i tryed to put in code tag but i don't know what didn't work so i had to put it pastebin =/

Comment: Check here for how to do that, or search for resources on AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html